# Authentication between phonegap and meteor?

Tags: node.js, cordova, oauth, meteor

Since the release [0.8.1](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/04/30/meteor-081-important-oauth-update) of MeteorJS Framework, there has been a fix on authentication. I haven't been able to authenticate from the phonegap app anymore with their new updates.

The problem:

1. When login with oauth flow from meteor, it's necessary to open a new popup window in phonegap. This can be obtain using the InAppBrowser module of phonegap, however, when the authentication is done on 3rd party and return to meteor server. This windows does not close and did not authenticate properly.
2. Using window.opener is problematic in some mobile environments (Cordova, Windows Phone), and it is not ideal because it requires the main app window to be on the same origin as the OAuth popup window.*

The question is, is there anyone was able to implement the authentication between phonegap and meteor? What's your solution to this problem?

Are there any alternative to the authentication that you recommend? (oAuth.io?) And how do you implement it?

Thank you